# Why is this an equality? $\frac{1}{4z^3} = \frac{-z}{4}$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Why is this an equality?

$$\frac{1}{4z^3} = \frac{-z}{4}$$

When $z = e^{iπ/4}$? I don't see how rhs is obtained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:
$$z^4=(e^{i\pi/4})^4=e^{i\pi}=-1\ ,$$
so
$$z=\frac{-1}{z^3}\ ,$$
so
$$-z=\frac1{z^3}\ ,$$
so
$$\frac{-z}4=\frac1{4z^3}\ .$$

Comment: Excellent! Thanks David, I've been blind for days 

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{4z^3}=\frac{-z}{4} \Rightarrow z^4=-1 \Rightarrow z^4=e^{iπ}$

now observe that $z=e^{i\frac{(π+2nπ)}{4}}$ $n\in \Bbb Z$ and therefor $z=e^{i\frac{π}{4}}$ is a root of $z^4=-1$

Comment: If you only use implications (not equivalences) as above, you don't quite prove what the OP asked.